# IBM Quantum "Jobs" web page problem: "Tags" always missing

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I tried to edit the tags and saved them, but the "Jobs" page displays empty tags always. Is that a bug? Did I do it incorrectly?
[image]
[image: IBM Quantum Jobs]

Comment: I tried on the platform and succeeded, could you tell me what you did exactly?

Comment: @Lena did you get something in the "Tags" column despite not adding anything there yourself?

Comment: @Lena I click the the tag button on one of the jobs. The "Job Tags" pops up. I write some texts there and press "Save". After that, the "Tags" column is empty.

Comment: When you write the name of the tag, say blabla, do you click on "Create new tag *blabla*" right below the bar before saving?

Comment: That's it. It works now. The "Create new tag..." does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Happy to know :)